# listbox item click event?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i binded some items to listbox.whenever click on particular listitem i want to display that subitems in another page.

Please tell me how to acheive this.

how to get the listitem id whenever click on particular list item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code created as part of a new DataBound application. It does just this.

Answer (score 28):

To clarify (in case you don't feel like creating a new DataBound application and just want the answer), instead of depending on the click event for a listbox item, you should be looking at the **selectionchanged event for the list box** itself.

eg:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">


// Handle selection changed on ListBox
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
    if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    // Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: @Blakomen:and what is else condition

Answer (score 1):

MVVM solution

Use the following libraries:

```
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71" 
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" <-- (optional, only for the ContextMenu)
```

XAML Example:

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="categoryListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                                    Command="{Binding Main.OpenCategoryCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove" />
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Show" />
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Note}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple command binding MVVM style to an item in a list, you can also enclose the whole item template in a button and hook up the Command property of the button like this:

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Button Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommandOnItemViewModel, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Button.Template>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- Your listitem styling goes here -->
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
          </Button>

        </ControlTemplate>

      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```